# how to use recursive make with an option telling it not to travel down the tree if needed?

Tags: makefile

I setup make to build my tree using recursive make. So the setup is

```
A/Makefile  a.c
A/B/Makefile a.c
A/B/C/Makefile a.c
```

where if I issue the command `make all` from level A/ then make will travel down the tree building everything and then come back up. Each Makefile contains a list of folders below it to build. There is a common.inc file in the root which is read in each Makefile.

This is just a standard layout for recursive make, and nothing new. The details is gives in many places.  [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recursion.html) and [here](http://lackof.org/taggart/hacking/make-example/) are examples.

My question is this:  many times I'd like to do `make all` but only build things in the current folder, and not actually travel down the tree, may be because I want to test some changes in the current folder at this time. So I end up editing the current folder's Makefile by commenting out the `SUBDIRS=A B C` which lists all folders below, or by adding new special targets for this folder only. Both are annoying things to have to keep doing.

Does any one have an idea or a small example of a recursive makefile that uses a switch to tell it if it should travel down the tree or not when called? may be there is a way to call make and pass it some flag at the command line, and this flag is used to  remove `SUBDIRS=A B C .....` list so it only stops at the current folder level?

Just to be clear. I am using standard SUBDIRS in the Rules.mk, which each Makefile in the tree includes. Here is the part. I copied this from the net long time ago

```
$(SUBDIRS)::
    @if test -d $@; then                \
        set $(EXIT_ON_ERROR);           \
        echo "cd $@; make $@";          \
        cd $@; make $@;             \
        set +e;                 \
    else                        \
        echo "Skipping non-directory $@...";    \
    fi                      \
    $(CLICK_STOPWATCH);
endif
```

and in each folder Makefile I write

```
SUBDIRS = A B C        
include Rules.mk

all:: .......
```

Then I just write  `make all` to build. If there is a way to do `make all LOOP=0` where LOOP is some value I pass it or an option or a string or something and then change the above `SUBDIRS` logic to check for the value of this `LOOP` and based on the value then do the recursive make or not, then the problem is solved. The default can be to `LOOP=1` if it is missing from the command line.

But I do not know enough Make to program this type of logic.

Comment: there is a option in make utility which will let you know how many child directories its been to , a "if" check with that might work for you ..... i dont remember it though -- need to check the old dusty notes :(  .... iff you have time try a search in the gnu make manual , its there.

Comment: You can do it by set env var at the call of `make all`, just edited my post for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use power of rules' depencies. Add your sources files to the dependencies of the rule called from the "root Makefile". If these files are up to date, the recursivity in an folder will stop because the rule is 'up-to-date', and nothing will be done.
Don't add .PHONY for all your rules in the sub-directory Makefile, otherwise recursives rules will be called.

Play with the dependencies of the rules can be the key to not make recursive call, but if you  modify sources in each folder and want to build only from the root Makfile,  you have to create another rules.  With `make all`, the make binary may not know if you want build all your projet or not (if all your sources has been modified).

**EDIT:** choice by the command line

You're near the answer, you can set env var while calling your `make all` and test the value to decide calling recursivly or not.

```
    CC=g++
    SUBDIR=a b

    all: ${SUBDIR} main.cc
          ${CC} main.cc

    ${SUBDIR}:
    ifneq ($(MK_LOOP), 0)
        @echo "trust the recursivity !"
        ${MAKE} -C $@
    endif

    .PHONY: ${SUBDIR}
```

If you don't set the `MK_LOOP` var or you set to something else than 0, it will not be equal to 0 so recursive Makefile will be call; if you set to 0, `$(SUBDIR)` rule do nothing

```
    42SH $ MK_LOOP=0 make      # no recur
    42SH $ make all
    trust the recursivity !
    42SH $ make all MK_LOOP=1                # recur by default; same as : make all
    trust the recursivity !
    42SH $
```

Comment: thanks. nice trick of passing the variable from command line to make like this. it works.